# Xcode How to remove image after a number of touches?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have touch event animations of 'clouds' using this code. All working fine but I want to fade/remove clouds after the user taps the cloud 3 times. So I want them to disappear after the third time it is touched. How do I do this?

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGRect cloudBLRect = [[[self.cloudBL layer] presentationLayer] frame];


if (CGRectContainsPoint(cloudBLRect, touchLocation)) {
    NSLog(@"cloudBL tapped!");

    cloudBLPressed = true;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.cloudBL.center = CGPointMake(200, 600);
                         self.cloudBL.alpha = 0.5;


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                               delay:2.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{

                                               self.cloudBL.center = CGPointMake(100, 700);
                                              self.cloudBL.alpha = 0.5;


                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              self.cloudBL.alpha = 1.0;


                                          }];


   } else {
            NSLog(@"cloud not tapped.");
            return;
                      }



 if (cloudBLPressed) return;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a variable `count` and initialize it to 0. On each touch, increment it by 1. Also check in the touchGesture method, that if the `count` variable equals to 2 then set `alpha` for the cloud to `0.0`.

Something like this:
in .m file take a private int vairiable: `int count;
 in viewDidLoad: count = 0; cloudView.alpha = 1.0;`

```
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
count++;
if(count<2)
{
     cloudView.alpha-=0.33;
} 

else {
    cloudView.alpha = 0.0;
}
              }
```

Add it in your animation logic. Hope that helps.

You can set it in your code like this:

```
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGRect cloudBLRect = [[[self.cloudBL layer] presentationLayer] frame];

    if(count < 2)
    {
        count++;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(cloudBLRect, touchLocation)) {
        NSLog(@"cloudBL tapped!");

        cloudBLPressed = true;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.cloudBL.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);
//                             self.cloudBL.alpha -=0.33;


                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                                   delay:2.0
                                                 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                              animations:^{

                                                  self.cloudBL.center = CGPointMake(100, 300);
                                                  self.cloudBL.alpha -=0.33;


                                              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
//                                                  self.cloudBL.alpha = 1.0;


                                              }];


                         }];
    }

         else {
                             NSLog(@"cloud not tapped.");
                             return;
                         }



         if (cloudBLPressed) return;

    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                              delay:2.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{

                             self.cloudBL.center = CGPointMake(100, 300);
                             self.cloudBL.alpha =0.0;


                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tripleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:)];

tripleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;

[yourView addGestureRecognizer:tripleTap];
```

Comment: That would require user to triple-tap on image (fast)

Comment: Than set a single tap gesture and an iterator on a subclass of `UITapGestureRecognier` could be a solution.

Comment: in a game the taps may be not happening in regular sequence. it may be possible, the player touches 3 clouds in order of 1-2-1-3-2-3-3-2-1. your solution would work only in the case of 1-1-1-2-2-2-3-3-3 only, which is a highly unlikely scenario, the events always happen in irregular way.

Comment: Not if you add a simple gesture to the view (here a cloud) with an iterator inside that increase each time to tap on it. When you tap it and that is the 3rd time, then you can remove the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnImage:)];
[cloud addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

}

```
- (void)tapOnImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    tapsCounter++;

    if (tapsCounter == 3)
    {
        // do your stuff

        tapsCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to move this logic into `UIImageView` subclass that represents the **cloud** object.

Answer (score 0):

Add the proper delegate `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your interface.

Then in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMethod)];
tapped.delegate=self;
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

and then in your View Controller:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    if (touch.view != cloudView&& cloudView) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)tapMethod 
{
    [cloudView removeFromSuperview];
    cloudView = nil;
}
```